# How to make a Search box in DHTMLX grid selected initially?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I have a DHTMLX grid with Search box fields in the header.

How can I make sure that one of the search box fields is selected on startup of the grid?

Comment: what do you mean by "selected", is that a "`#select_filter`" type of box?

Comment: With selected i mean 'How can i set the focus on this field ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery to position the cursor in to the first filter box. As DHTMLX does not provide IDs for the fields, you have to address the box by it's class name, something like this:

```
jQuery(".hdrcell").first().children().first().focus();
```

The according box usually looks like:

```
<td style="cursor: default;">
    <div class="hdrcell filter">
      <input type="text" style="color:grey;width:90%;font-size:7pt;font-family:Arial;-moz-user-select:text;">
    </div>
</td>
```